# Lookup values from a MapType column with keys from another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark streaming dataframe with two columns. An Integer id column and a MapType column with an Integer Id as key and a JSON object as value.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id             objects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    (1 -> {"id" : 1, "type": "jpeg"}, 2 -> {"id" : 2, "type": "gif"}, 3 -> {"id" : 3, "type": "png"})
5     |    (1 -> {"id" : 1, "type": "jpeg"}, 2 -> {"id" : 2, "type": "gif"}, 3 -> {"id" : 3, "type": "png"})
2     |    (1 -> {"id" : 1, "type": "jpeg"}, 2 -> {"id" : 2, "type": "gif"}, 3 -> {"id" : 3, "type": "png"})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to construct a new dataframe that has a single column containing the JSON object whose key matches the id column.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
objects
----------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id" : 1, "type": "jpeg"}
{"id" : 2, "type": "gif" }
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's the best way to do this? I implemented a Scala udf that does the lookup and returns the corresponding object value, but was wondering if the same can be done using built in Spark functions.

I tried to do something like this:

```
df.withColumn("obj", $"objects".getItem($"id"))
```

But it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
```

which makes sense since `$"id"` is a column type. However, if I do a collect that would result in an action which I hope to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for an UDF, you can use the inbuilt functionality to do this. However, you can't use `getItem`, since the argument is another column, not a string value.

Instead you can get values from the Map as follows:

```
df.withColumn("value", $"objects"($"id"))
```

To create a new dataframe and remove the rows where the id does not exist in the Map,

```
df.select($"objects"($"id").as("objects")).na.drop
```

which will give you,

```
+-------------------------+
|objects                  |
+-------------------------+
|{"id": 1, "type": "jpeg"}|
|{"id": 3, "type": "png"} |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: What will this be in pyspark?

Comment: @LouisYang: If you want to take elements from the map using a string, you can simply use `getItem`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem. If you want to use a column, you could try the above solution but simply removing all `$` (I haven't actually tested this).